# How can I remove left UIBarButtonItem's background

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonitemstyle

I tried to remove the background of the left UIBarButtonItem's background.

[image: UIBarButtonItem]

My image is just the icon with the lines. But there is black background.
My code is:

```
paneViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuicon"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(navigationPaneBarButtonItemTapped:)];
paneViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Where am I wrong?

Update:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menuicon"];
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton setImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height);

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(navigationPaneBarButtonItemTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];
paneViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton;
```

That worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Create the object as a UIButton and then call initWithCustomView: on the UIBarButtonItem instead.

Comment: Guess I should post as an answer, heh. I do love writing comments though, glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the object as a UIButton (do all the usual setup; frame, target, background image... etc) and then call `initWithCustomView:` on the `UIBarButtonItem` instead.

Answer (score 0):

this works as well:

```
UIBarButtonItem *navButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbutton.png"]
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                 target:self
                                                                 action:@selector(buttonPressed)] autorelease];


NSArray *buttonArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navButton, nil];

TransparentToolbar *toolbar = [[[TransparentToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0, 44.0f, 44.0f)] autorelease];
toolbar.items = buttonArray;

UIBarButtonItem *controls = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolbar] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = controls;
```